# r - In is.not.number.warning(x)

Tags: r, data.table, kruskal-wallis, terr

I have a problem to perform a kruskal wallis test with package data.table and module Terr on RStudio.

Variables :

```
$WL_TEST_Q1: num[1:41725]
$SPLIT: chr[1:41725]
$TEST_NUM_NAME: chr[1:41725]
```

Code :

```
setDT(DT)
KwTestQ1 <- DT[!is.na(WL_TEST_Q1), .(SPLIT,WL_TEST_Q1,TEST_NUM_NAME)][,kruskal.test("WL_TEST_Q1" ~ factor("SPLIT"), na.action = "na.omit"), 
              by = .(TEST_NUM_NAME)][,c("data.name","method","parameter","statistic"):=NULL]
setnames(KwTestQ1, "p.value", "p.value Q1")
```

With module R 3.3.2 and without quotes, it works fine but not with module Terr on RStudio. I'm using Terr R_4.2.0.35.

I have this error :

```
1: In is.not.number.warning(x) : x is not a numeric dataset
2: In function(x, g, ...) : 1 observations (x[i], g[i]) with NA in 'x' removed.
```

I don't know what it means.